# Number of results from elasticserch fuzzy_like_this_field influence "good" results being returned

Tags: python, search, autocomplete, lucene, elasticsearch

Sorry for the lousy title, but let me explain the problem I'm having.  I'm currently working on a project, and a part of this includes a search engine for addresses, which I have in elasticsearch.  What I'm trying to do is use fuzzy_like_this_field queries when a new character is entered in my search bar to generate autocomplete results and try to "guess" which of the (~1 million) addresses the user is typing.

My issue is that I currently have a size limit on my query, as returning all of the results was both unnecessary and expensive, time-wise.  My issue, is that I often am not getting the "correct" result unless I return 1000 or more results from the query.  For example, if I enter "100 broad" in trying to search for "100 broadway" and I only return 200 results (about the max that I can do without it taking too long), 100 broadway is nowhere to be found, even though all of the returned results have a higher levenshtein distance than the result that I want.  I get "100 broadway" as the first result if I return 2000 results from my query, but it takes too long.  I can't even filter the results that got returned to bring the correct one to the top, because it's not being returned.

Shouldn't putting a size limit of N on the query return the best N results, not a seemingly random subset of them?

Sorry if this is poorly worded or too vague.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have some misapprehensions about the [`fuzzy_like_this` query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/flt-query/).

> Fuzzifies ALL terms provided as strings and then picks the best n differentiating terms...For each source term the fuzzy variants are held in a BooleanQuery with no coord factor...

If you just want a fuzzy search based on Levenshtein distance, use a [`fuzzy` query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/fuzzy-query/)

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom analyzer using the edge ngram tokenizer which would help you achieve what you are looking for. Find here a technique demonstrated by elasticsearch
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_index_time_search_as_you_type.html

Then doing a simple query such as

```
{
    "query": {
        "match":{
            "address": "100 Broadway"
         }
      }
}
```

would do you the job. You might also consider using a different analyzer for the search which is also shown in the tutorial (In the end). This will enable you to do stuff such as tokenizing your search query and preprocessing it in a manner different from the index analyisis.